# Product topology and projection mappings.

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. Now let us consider projection mappings $p_1$ and $p_2$ defined from the product set of $X$ and $Y$ to $X$ and $Y$ respectively .The lecture notes I am going through says that if $U$ is an open set in $X$ and $V$ is an open set in $Y$ then the set product of $U$ and $V$ is the intersection of the inverses of the projection mappings defined from $X \times Y$ to $X$ and $X \times Y$ to $Y$ respectively .
Can I find a rigorous explanation for this aforementioned argument ?

Comment: This is very easy to check. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is $U \times V = p_1^{-1}[U] \cap p_2^{-1}[V]$.

The left hand side is exactly those $(x,y)$ that satisfy $x \in U$ and $y \in V$, by the definition of a Cartesian product of sets.

The right hand side consists of all those pairs $(x,y)$ such that both $p_1(x,y) = x$ is in $U$ *and* (because of the intersection) such that $p_2(x,y) = y$ is in $V$.

So clearly these are the same sets.

Comment: Ok , if I am getting it right then , for a given value of x in U , there can be many values of the inverse in the product set and so is it for any y in V and this is why the intersection to select only ordered pairs falling in common as the inverse , right ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. $p_1^{-1}[U]$ is all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x \in U$ and no condition on $y$, hence the intersection with the other set.

Comment: Bbrandsma : Thanks a  lot